# Back date getting printed while converting the date to oracle date format

Tags: javascript, oracle, date

I am converting the javascript date into oracle date format and it keeps on printing old date. Please consider the following code. I was expecting `13-DEC-2016` to get printed in the `alert ("Printing Full Date: "+fullStartOracleDate);` dialog but it keeps on printing `2-DEC-2016` for some reason. It's demonstrated in the [JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zdcm19cs/)

```
var assignedOnDate = "12/13/2016";
var  myJSDate = new Date(assignedOnDate);


alert ("Printing Date: "+assignedOnDate);

var monthNames =  ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" ];

  var month = myJSDate.getMonth();
  var year = myJSDate.getFullYear();
  var day = myJSDate.getDay();

  var fullStartOracleDate  = day+"-"+monthNames[month]+"-"+year;

  alert ("Printing Full Date: "+fullStartOracleDate);
```

Comment: the getDay() method returns the numeric day of the week ranging from 0 for Sunday through 6 for Saturday.  the getDate() method returns the day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use getDate for day

`var assignedOnDate = "12/13/2016";
var  myJSDate = new Date(assignedOnDate);
alert ("Printing Date: "+assignedOnDate);
var monthNames =  ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" ];
  var month = myJSDate.getMonth();
  var year = myJSDate.getFullYear();
  var day = myJSDate.getDate();
  var fullStartOracleDate  = day+"-"+monthNames[month]+"-"+year;
  alert ("Printing Full Date: "+fullStartOracleDate);`